# Solicitar postagem reversa API Correios

Tags: python, web-service

Estou tentando utilizar a API dos Correios para realizar o método de postagem reversa. Estou usando o seguinte link para acessar esse método:

http://webservicescol.correios.com.br/ScolWeb/WebServiceScol?wsdl

Sempre que tento acessar esse método pelo script eu tenho esse error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Temporarily Unavailable for url: http://webservicescol.correios.com.br/ScolWeb/WebServiceScol?wsdl
```

Aparentemente esse link que estou tentando realizar o request está com problemas. Já fiz testes de outros métodos que funcionaram nesse outro link:

https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl

Vocês sabem se teria algum outro método equivalente ao de solicitar postagem reversa ou outro link para eu acessar esse método?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente uma olhada no wrapper da API dos correios mantido pela Olist - é um projeto bem legal que usa muita coisa dos correios. Se não quiser usar o projeto todo, pode explorar o código e ver como são feitas as requisições de postagem reversa -

https://github.com/olist/correios